# How do you save a contact onto the home screen?

Tags: home-screen, home-screen-shortcuts, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I can't figure out how to save a contact shortcut on the home screen for easy dialing (Ice Cream Sandwich on Galaxy Nexus).

Long-pressing on the home screen prompts me to choose a wallpaper. Long-pressing on a contact in the People app has no effect. I can't find any menu option to do it.

How do you do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it. There's a **Direct dial** widget you can add from the Applications/Widgets menu. When you select this, it prompts you to choose a contact.

There are also shortcut widgets for **Direct message**, **Open contact**, etc.

Comment: FYI, you should click the checkmark next to your self-answer to mark this as answered :)

Comment: I will do in 2 days as soon as I am able.

Comment: Oh - I didn't realize there was a time limit? My bad :P